# Understanding a proof by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

In the following proof by induction:

Problem: Prove by induction that $1+3+ \ldots+ \ (2n-1)=n^2$

Answer:

a) $P(1)$ is true since $1^2=1$

b)Adding $2n+1$ to both sides we obtain:
$$
1+3+..+(2n-1)+(2n+1)=n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2
$$
Why $2n+1$ ? Where does this come from?

And how does knowing that
$$
1+3+ \ldots +(2n-1)+(2n+1)=(n+1)^2
$$
prove anything?

Appreciate any light, thanks.

Comment: there is another, more simple proof. Would you like me to make an answer of it?

Comment: Sure,  go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

$P(n)$ is the statement $1+3+\dots+(2n-1)=n^2$. To carry out a proof by induction, you must establish the base case $P(1)$, and then show that if $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ is also true.

In this problem, $P(n+1)$ is the statement $1+3+\dots+(2n-1)+(2n+1)=(n+1)^2$, because $2(n+1)-1=2n+1$. So by starting with $P(n)$ and adding $2n+1$ to both sides, you can prove $P(n+1)$.

Comment: Got it, the author plugged $(n+1)$ into $2n-1$, expanded and shortened to generate the last term and then added it to both sides. Thanks!

Comment: Then he plugged $(n+1)$ into $n^2$ and demonstrated that both results have the same meanings. The idea is that if you add the generated term to both sides, and find out it´s the same as plugging $n+1$ to the right side, you have found that $P(n+1)$ is the same in both sides, and hence they represent the same sequence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the assertion holds for all integers less than or equal to $n$. We want to show that it holds for $n+1$. By assumption, we have
$$
1+3+\cdots+(2n-1) = n^2
$$
Adding $(2n+1)$ to both sides, we have
$$
1+3+\cdots+(2n-1)+(2n+1) = n^2 + 2n+1 = (n+1)^2
$$
Hence, we have that
$$
1+3+\cdots+(2(n+1)-3)+(2(n+1)-1) = (n+1)^2
$$
So the assertion holds for $n+1$. This proves that the assertion holds for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a proof by induction is to

1. Show that the Proof $P$ holds for $P(1)$
2. Assume the proof holds for $P(k), \ k \in N$
3. *Show* that the proof holds for $P(k + 1), \ k \in N$

The reason this works is because if the proof works for $P(1)$, and we know that the proof will work for *all* $k + 1$, we can say $k = 2$ and have the proof work for $P(2)$. Repeating this process, we can have the proof work for all $P(n), n \in N$

Considering this, your $P(n)$ was that

$$P(n): 1 + 3 + \ldots + (2n - 1) = n^2$$

Using this framework, can you try the proof out again?

Comment: That's the wrong $P(n)$.

Comment: fixed the error, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, "prooving by exhaustion" is trivial, it´s the process of going from "exhaustion of confirmation cases" to "assumption of all cases covered" that got me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof, which does not rely on induction.

$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} (2i-1)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} 2i-\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N}1$

Now, use the fact that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N}i=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$. This can be proved a variety of ways, including induction.

$$2\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} i-\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N}1=2\frac{N(N+1)}{2}-N=N^2+N-N=N^2$$